# Shemonei Esrei regarding the seasons in Divine Might

Tags: calendar, shemoneh-esrei, geography, weather

Every time I pray the Amidah, I get very hesitant regarding what season is appropriate for me to  pray. I live in the southern hemisphere in a tropical climate. Therefore, we have one season dry and cold, one season hot and humid, and lastly a season of monsoon.

I have been tempted to pray in accord with the seasons of Israel. But I would be glad if some one would explain if that is permissible?

Comment: I have no links handy but we pray in accordance with the agricultural seasons and needs in Israel. Your prayer book should indicate the dates when we change texts.

Comment: See also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/saying-mashiv-haruach-in-the-southern-hemisphere