# Southern Birkas Ha'ilanos

Tags: halacha, blessing, calendar, geography, see-sight-vision-blind

I've seen [Saying Mashiv HaRuach in the Southern Hemisphere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/saying-mashiv-haruach-in-the-southern-hemisphere). Similarly, is Birkas Ha'ilanos (ברכת האילנות) said in Tishrei in the southern hemisphere?  That's when the trees bloom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Ritva writes ([Rosh Hashana 11a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40903&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=)):

> ויומי ניסן לאו דוקא אלא כל מקום ומקום לפי מה שהוא דמלבלבי.‏
>   "The days of Nissan" is not precise, but rather every place according to when the trees bud.

Based on this, Rabbis [Yitzchok Yaakov Weiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Yaakov_Weiss) ([Minchat Yitzchak 10:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&pgnum=312)) and [Tzvi Pesach Frank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzvi_Pesach_Frank) ([Har Tzvi OC 118](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20947&st=&pgnum=122)) ruled that in the Southern Hemisphere the blessing should be recited in Tishrei/Cheshvan when the local trees actually start budding.